# Order of drawing cards in 2-7 Triple Draw

Tags: rules, drawing, 2-7

Suppose A, B, C, D and E are playing 2-7 Draw poker together, sitting on a table in that exact order. A is the button and B and C are SB and BB respectively. I know that the players announce the number of cards they would like to decide in the following order: B-C-D-E-A. However I am not sure whether each player is dealt the entire replacement or they take turns receiving one card at a time. Let's say in one round the five players replace the following amount of cards: A-1, B-3, C-4, D-2, E-3.

In the first model, the cards would be dealt like this: B-B-B, C-C-C-C, D-D, E-E-E, A. On the contrary the second model would look like this: B-C-D-E-A, B-C-D-E, B-C-E, C. Which of these two, if any, is the standard drawing mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

In the order you mentioned. Player B will receive their cards first, followed by C next, then D, E and finally A.

Example:

- Player A wants one card, Player B two cards, Player C stand pats, Player D folds and Player E wants two cards.
- Player B will get two cards first, Player C will get nothing as they're happy, Player D folds, next Player E gets two cards, then finally Player A gets one card.

The game follows the order of action set by the button and the blinds. In the example of the two you asked about, B-B-B, C-C-C-C, D-D, E-E-E, A, is the correct order.